# MDX Modelisation of a slow changing dimension

Tags: database-design, mdx

I have a MDX Dimension , whose main hierarchy has the following levels  :

1. **Product Line** key : PLid
2. **Profit Center** key : PCid
3. **Team**  key : TEid
4. **Employee** ( binding level to my fact tables )
  key: EMPid

This one works fine, but the users want a flexible upper part of the hierarchy, that varies from year to year

1. **Year**
2. **Product Line**
3. **Profit Center**
4. **Team**
5. **Employee**

with the attribute relationship "Product Line" -> "Profit Center" varying a lot from year to year, and Profit Center -> Team -> Employee remaining constant.

The problem I have is that facts are more than often linked  to more than one element of this new hierarchy. And I found that elements are not dispatched properly following this hierarchy, I have the global total at all level.

I have a table giving the association ( Year, PLid, PCid)

What I can't do is forcefully binding elements of the fact table on this new hierarchy, because creating year * nb employees would be too much. and the head part can be changed on a whim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where a many-to-many dimension relationship works.

I Build a [Yearly Association] dimension  defined on the association table, also used this dimension as a fact table, regularly bound on the Employee dimension, and defined a many-to-many relationship association between [Yearly Association] and the other facts table.